# What are all the different uses of the [square brackets] in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I'm coming across the square bracket `[]` syntax quite a bit in Ruby, but it never seems to be doing the same thing. Can anyone list *all* the different uses for the square brackets `[]` in Ruby so my mind can get a handle on this seemingly endlessly versatile little symbol? (How is it possible that one symbol can do so much without the Ruby interpreter getting confused?)

Examples:

- `[]` and `[]=` methods
- `%q[...]`
- `[1,2,3][0]`
- `hash["a"] = 3`
- `ary = []`
- `/[^A-Fa-f0-9]/`
- `"Is a string"[5,3]`

Comment: Go to http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ and type `[]` into the "Methods" search box, that will give you a list of its uses in the core. Non-core classes can, of course, provide their own implementations for the `[]` and `[]=` operators.

Comment: [] and []= methods are no problem , what about %w[ a b c ] and [1,2,3][1] array indexing? What else? `[]` is popping up all over the place and I'm starting to get uneasy about what I don't know.

Comment: It's confusing to new rubyists that [] is a method and not an operator. The downvotes for this question are unfair.

Comment: @pguardiario: **Every** operator in Ruby is implemented as a method. In fact, the whole concept of operators in Ruby is more or less syntactic sugar only. But that's an implementation detail that normally doesn't matter. And when treating it as an operator, it still requires to check the exact definition of the operator depending on the operands. This definition (the semantics) differs between operands while the syntax is always the same. But this applies to all languages, even when just considering numeric addition or string concatenation with `+` or division between an integer and a float.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay, just for my own notes I have gone and had a closer look at this and, building on [Holger Just's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10877685/405983), come up with the following: the use of square brackets in Ruby can be divided into 6 uses, 3 of them a part of Ruby's method definitions and 3 of them semantic constructs.

***Method definition***

**Object creation via class methods Array::[], Hash::[]**

```
Array.[](1,2,3) #=> [1,2,3]                        #Un-sugared notation
Array["a","b","c"] #=> ["a","b","c"]               #Sugared equivalent
Hash["a", 100, "b", 200] #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
```

Nothing to do with literal constructors, although it does the same thing.

**Element reference via instance methods Array#[], Bignum#[], Continuation#[], Fixnum#[], Hash#[], MatchData#[], Method#[], Proc#[], String#[], Struct#[], Symbol#[], Thread#[], and class methods Dir::[], ENV::[]**

```
ary = [1,2,"abc", [15,16,[26,27]]]  
ary.[](2) #=> "abc"                #Un-sugared notation
ary[2] #=> "abc"                   #Sugared equivalent
ary[0,2] #=> [1,2]  
ary[3][2][1] #=> 26  
[1,2,3][0] #=> 1  
"Is a string"[7,3] #=> "rin"
```

**Element assignment via instance methods Array#[]=, Hash#[]=, String#[]=, Struct#[]=, Thread#[]=, and class method ENV::[]=**

```
ary = [1,2,3]  
ary.[]=(1,"abc") #=> [1,"abc",3]    #un-sugared notation
ary[2] = "def" #=> [1,"abc","def"]  #Sugared equivalent
hash = {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}  
hash["a"] = 3 #=> {"a"=>3, "b"=>2}
```

***Semantic constructs***

**Object creation via the array literal constructor**

```
ary = []
```

There are a bunch of literal constructors in Ruby that create an object of the relevant class via the use of (usually) a simple symbol pair, square brackets being the literal constructor for array objects: Array `[]`, Hash `{}`, Proc `->(){}`, Range `..` and `...`, Regexp `//`, String `""` and `''`, Symbol `:` and `:""`.

**Object creation via the % notation**

```
%q[hello there you] #=> "hello there you"           # String % notation  
%w[hello there you] #=> ["hello", "there", "you"]   # Array % notation
```

It is not, strictly speaking, square-bracket notation, but rather two-symbol-pair notation of which you can use square brackets if you wish. So `%q@hello there you@` is equally valid.

**Ruby's regular expressions**

```
/[^A-Fa-f0-9]/
```

Square brackets indicate character classes in Ruby regular expressions.

I did find another use of the `[]`, as a pattern for use in the Dir::glob method, but its supposed to act exactly as it does in regular expressions. Still, it indicates that there are possibly more uses hidden away in Ruby's 1500+ methods.

Answer (score 12):

The square brackets are in two strict contexts and one optional one:

**Defining Arrays**
Arrays, i.e. a data structure providing and ordered list of elements can be specified in code by using a syntax like `[1,2,3]`. This creates an array with the three elements `1`, `2`, and `3` in exactly that order. you can then iterate over the array using on of the iterator functions like `each` or `map` or you can directly access a specific elements by its index id as shown below.

**Accessing Elements in Arrays and Hashes**
Hashes (also called hashmaps, dictionaries, or associative arrays in other languages) also contain elements similar to arrays. The are different from this in the way that they store their data *unordered*. Data is not accessed by an integer id as is the case by arrays but with an arbitrary key (commonly a symbol or a string). This is different from e.g. PHP where the same Array type is used for both.

This access to the data is facilitated by methods called `[]` and `[]=` for both hashes and arrays.

```
my_array = [:a, :b, :c]
second_element = my_array[1]
# => :b
# notice that the first element in arrays always has the index 0

my_hash = {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3}
element_of_b = my_hash[:b]
# => 2
```

This is the common use case for the brackets. In Ruby code, you might sometimes see other classes implementing the bracket functions. They do so to allow an access similar to either arrays or hashes and it is then generally expected that these classes behave similar to those but this is in no way enforced. See also [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

**% Notation**
Ruby has a third syntax to create strings (and other objects) apart from the common. Using this syntax, the literal string in code are not enclosed by `"` or `'` but use a special delimiter. It starts with a percent sign, a single character specifying the object to be created and almost any character to chose as a delimiter:

```
a = %w[foo bar baz]
b = %w{foo bar baz}
c = %wxfoo bar bazx
d = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

All three example create the same array. Please see the some [documentation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation) on how to use this syntax and which other modifier characters are available in Ruby.

While it is common to use brackets here, it is on no way required and can be substituted if required. It is just advisory here as the most common usage of this notation is to create an array of elements from a whitespace-seperated string (as seen above). As such, the usage of brackets makes it further clear that an array is returned as the syntax looks similar to the basic array specification.

Comment: And yes, I know hashes are ordered in Ruby 1.9. But overly relying on that fact is going to be rather surprising when changing elements and in my eyes represents a rape of the data structure. I like my hashes unordered :)

Comment: Thx very much. However, the main purpose of my question is to get a complete list of the uses of `[]` rather than an explanation of each use (although that would be a nice bonus). I want someone to list off the uses of `[]` then tell me "that's all there is". Are there lots more uses, maybe over 10, or just the ones in my examples in the original question? (I've just learned of another use: the calling of anonymous functions, what ever they are.)

Comment: Well, you have the syntax elements I mentioned above. There are no more than this. However, many classes implement the `[]` methods where they mean different things. There can't be an exhaustive list for these usages. Another example is that the `Proc` class implements the `[]` method to mean call the proc. But that's not a new usage but just applies the second method mentioned above. Generally, all you have to do is to identify one of the above mentioned patterns. If it's the second you have to consult the documentation to find out what the semantics of the respective method are.

Comment: Okay, I must be getting confused. What about the use of `[]` in regular expressions, e.g. `/[^A-Fa-f0-9]/`. Where does this fit into the three uses you mention above? I don't see a `[]` method defined in Ruby's Regex class? (I understand that different methods define `[]` in different ways and am not asking for all of them to be explained, just that knowing `[]` means different things to different classes will do.)

Comment: (Bloody 5min limit on editing). Edit to previous post *I understand different **built-in Ruby classes** define `[]` in different ways...

Comment: When a character (a square bracket or any other) is within a regular expression, it is not Ruby anymore, it's the language for regular expressions (coincidentally used in Ruby's core library for regular expressions). More or less as if you have a string `"Hello world!"`  in a Ruby program, and ask what is the meaning of the exclamation mark in Ruby.

Comment: It's not a distinction that is really relevant to the spirit of my question. Maybe if Regexp were only a part of the standard library or a gem it could be omitted, because then I would need to explore those for square bracket use which is expanding the scope a little too far.

Answer (score 0):

handy syntax for instantiating structs with square brackets

```rb
irb(main):001:0> Point = Struct.new(:x, :y)                         
=> Point                      
irb(main):002:0> point = Point[1,2]                                 
=> #<struct Point x=1, y=2>   
irb(main):003:0> point.x                   
=> 1                           
irb(main):004:0> point.y                    
=> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another much lesser known (and somewhat odd) use of square brackets in Ruby is in calling procs or lambdas. For example, if you define a lambda function:

```rb
add = ->(a, b) { a + b }
```

In order to call the lambda function, one would think you'd use `add(1, 2)`, but this will actually throw a `NoMethodError`. You *can*, however, call the lambda function with square brackets like so:

```rb
> add[1, 2]
=> 3
```